# OCLint reports compiler errors due to its inability to find #import-ed header files

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcodebuild, oclint

I am trying to integrate OCLint 0.13 to check lint violations in my ObjC based iOS project.

As per [this guide](http://oclint-docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/guide/xcode.html) I created an aggregate target in Xcode to run a `xcodebuild clean build` followed by `oclint-xcodebuild` to generate a `compile_commands.json`. I am able to run the `clang` command from the generated `compile_commands.json` file. However, in html report generated by `oclint-json-compilation-database` command, while processing file like `NEORepos/Public/ResourceObservables/NEOAggregatedObservable.h`, I see compiler errors like **`'NEOObservables/NEOObservable.h' file not found`** even though the said header file is present at `NEOObservables/Public/Observables/NEOObservable.h`.

[image]

How can I get rid of these compiler errors which are preventing **some** of my source files from being linted?

Running the clang command from `compile_commands.json` generates the `.o` file, but OCLint doesn't seem to be able to compile using the json file. 
I also tried adding a few more `-I` include paths, but it didn't help. All suggestions and pointers are welcome.

Here's a piece of (edited) log...

> xcode_clean_build_command = xcodebuild -workspace 'Neo.xcworkspace' -scheme 'NeoSampleApp' -configuration 'Debug' clean build -dry-run -derivedDataPath /Users/username/Documents/git/ios-neo_linter/build/Neo -sdk iphonesimulator CLANG_ENABLE_MODULE_DEBUGGING=NO CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED=NO CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY='' CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=NO ENABLE_BITCODE=NO COMPILER_INDEX_STORE_ENABLE=NO | tee xcodebuild.log
>
> ...
>
> /oclint-xcodebuild
>
> ...
>
> Generating the compile_commands.json ...
>
> Picking NEORepos/Public/ResourceObservables/NEOAggregatedObservable.m
>   Picking NeoSampleApp/main.m
>
> ...
>
> Shortlisted files for linting (2 out of 283) and creating a new compile_commands.json
>
> ...
>
> Compiling /Users/username/Documents/git/ios-neo_linter/NEORepos/Public/ResourceObservables/NEOAggregatedObservable.m - Failed
>   Compiling /Users/username/Documents/git/ios-neo_linter/NeoSampleApp/main.m - Success
>   Analyzing /Users/username/Documents/git/ios-neo_linter/NeoSampleApp/main.m - Done
>
> ...
>
> Generating lint report (if any)...
>
> ...
>
> Executing command: oclint-json-compilation-database -e Pods -v --  -list-enabled-rules -no-analytics -enable-global-analysis -verbose --report-type html -o oclint.html -extra-arg=-Wno-everything
>
> ...
>
> /usr/local/bin/oclint -p /Users/username/Documents/git/ios-neo_linter -list-enabled-rules -no-analytics -enable-global-analysis -verbose --report-type html -o oclint.html -extra-arg=-Wno-everything /Users/username/Documents/git/ios-neo_linter/NEORepos/Public/ResourceObservables/NEOAggregatedObservable.m /Users/username/Documents/git/ios-neo_linter/NeoSampleApp/main.m

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler error was due to the `-dry-run` flag that I was using. Since it was doing a dry run, it was not creating `.hmap` files that were needed (at least not in the right location) leading to `<blah>.h file not found` errors.

However, without `-dry-run` I would have to do a full build which is not acceptable for me. Will update if I find a solution with optimal performance.